# Moments of Kumaraswamy distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I am working on a problem that in one step of it I need to write down the moments of the Kumaraswamy distribution as a function of its lower order moment, meaning

$$M_k = some \, terms \times M_{k-1}$$.

The moments of the Kumaraswamy distribution is defined as

$$M_k = \beta \mathbf{B} (1+\frac{k}{\alpha},\beta)$$

(According to this reference: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1572312708000282)

I tried different ways to re-write this equation in terms of lower order moments but I couldn't succeed in finding an answer for it. I appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thank you.

Best regards,

Ehsan

Comment: Do you have a good reason to think that you can do this (where the *some terms* are not in the form of Gamma or Beta functions)?

Comment: Hello @David, yes I do. I am trying to couple it with problem related to quadrature methods and I need it to be in that way. I also thought at the other way defining $\alpha$ or $\beta$ with something like $1/\xi$ so that I find a term that is proportional to $M_k \propto \xi^k$, but I could not succeed. Thank you for taking a look into this question.